# Charles: How to only record document but excerpt js css request?

Tags: remote-debugging, charles-proxy

I can not find this kind of settings in Charles "Record Settings" dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Record Settings>Include>add

In 'Add' in the path field type in *.js

This should filter the recording to just .js files. You can do the same for css files.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer get opposite result as what I asked, but according to your solution, I just add *.js *.jpg etc. to Settings>Exclude>Add.

Comment: Ahhh, My apologies, I'm glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
Proxy -> Recording Settings -> Exclude
```

`In Path , add *.js` or *.svg, the files you want Charles Proxy to exclude from the Dashboard that records the network traffic
[image]